# Migrating data from non-partitioned schema to partitioned schema

Tags: oracle, data-migration, database-partitioning

Our application uses Oracle DB(12G). Currently the schema does not have any partitioning. We are planning to implement interval partitioning. How do I migrate existing data from non-partitioned schema to partitioned schema. Please let me know your suggestions.